# Add extra attribute to option through Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have the Need for an extra value of an Option. 
the following select is being populated through the options: groupItems, which contains an 'id', a 'description' and a 'period'.

```
    <select name="cb_group_1130" id="cb_group_1130" data-bind="options: groupItems(1130), optionsText : 'description',  optionsValue : 'id', optionsPeriod : 'period', value : selectedItem(1130)">
    <option value="0">First</option>
    <option value="1637">second</option>
    <option value="1638">third</option
</select>
```

in the above case the optionsPeriod: 'period' doesnt work...

I want to accomplish that the Knockout generated Option displays this:

```
<option value="0" period="2" >First</option>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `optionsAfterRender` option to [post process the rendered `option` elements](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#note-2-post-processing-the-generated-options):

And in your view model:

```
this.setPeriod = function (option, item) {
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {
            attr: {
                period: item.period
            }
        }, item);
    }
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by687/).

Comment: @user3350540 Hi, I'm glad that I helped. If my solution is working for you should consider to mark it as accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work so later visitors will know that your question is resolved.